# Draw a Constant Line in D3.js over another Line Graph

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, linegraph

The goal is to display a line as a threshold.

Here is the Line that is drawn from values.

*Note: The `lineGenerator` just takes the respective x, y from the zipped data.*

```
    svg
      .append('path')
      .data([d3.zip(xValues, yValues)])
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', '#000')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .attr('d', lineGenerator);
```

However, when I want to add an additional line graph on top that is just a constant, it doesn't seem to want to draw in the same scale. The line that's produced from the code below is about 1/8 of the total x values, and I know the `xExtent` is correct.

*Note: The `xExtent` is just the min/max of the X Values from the previous path.*

```
    svg
      .append('line')
      .attr('x1', xExtent)
      .attr('y1', 1.5)
      .attr('x2', xExtent[1])
      .attr('y2', 1.5)
      .attr('stroke', '#000')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5);
```

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong, as I would like this constant line to be displayed on top of the whole graph.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain(xDomain);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]).domain(yDomain);    

g.append('line')
   .attr('x1', xScale(xDomain[0]))
   .attr('y1', yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
   .attr('x2', xScale(xDomain[1]))
   .attr('y2', yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
   .attr('class', 'zeroline');
```